# Identificating user with Google account in Android application

Tags: android

I want to communicate with the server from my android app. The user needs to be identified, so somekind of login must be implemented.

Can I just take the Google account from AccountManager and be sure that it doesnt return any account the current user isnt logged in to?

That way there wouldnt be any need to ask any passwords or anything. It would be used only on first login, so that I could get some userID from the server.

Comment: Can you just ask the user to identify themselves (i.e. create a log in account in your app)?

Answer (score 0):

The Device ID may provide the uniqueness you are looking for:

```
Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
```

Comment: Using the deviceID would lead to unique devices, not unique users. If I can trust that the AccountManager returns only the accounts logged in, I could use the email-address.
Our server uses OpenID, but I havent found any simple way to get the users OpenID without directing the user to browser.